# Not able to import Specs2 in eclipse (scala-ide) project

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, specs2, scala-ide

Kindly consider if there's something very stupid I am missing, I am very new to this.

Creating [this](https://github.com/sequenceiq/sequenceiq-samples/tree/master/spark-correlation) example on Eclipse (Scala-ide). When I create the CorrelationJobTest.scala class, there's a problem in importing  classes from specs2 package.

```
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
```

The error I am getting is pretty obvious,

```
object specs2 is not a member of package org
```

Even after creating a build.sbt file, adding the dependencies, and doing a `sbt clean`, the error is still showing.
Below is my build.sbt

```
name := "SparkCorrelation"

organization := "com.xyz"

version := "0.1"


/* scala versions and options */
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// These options will be used for *all* versions.

javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation")
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-unchecked", "-deprecation")

/* dependencies */
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.7" % "test")

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

EDIT:
I faced this problem with apache.spark packages too. Then I included the jar `spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop-2.6.0.jar` and it got solved. Isn't there a library for specs2 that I can import in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Here's what I did:

1. Deleted the project from eclipse
2. Did `sbt eclipse`
3. Imported the project into eclipse again.
4. Added dependencies in `build.sbt`
5. Did `sbt clean`

The problem was that the project was directly created in eclipse and was not able to link to sbt build file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `junit` module to your dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.7" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % "3.7" % "test")
```

Comment: Added but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you create your specification file in `src/test/scala` and not `src/main/scala`?

Comment: You mean build.sbt? It is in the project folder. Do I have to create it somewhere else?

Comment: I was meaning the `CorrelationJobTest.scala` file but I can see it is in the right place. I'll try to see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: What I did was
1. Created an eclipse project
2. Created build.sbt, included the dependencies, did `sbt clean`
3. Created all the src files. 
4. Got this error

Comment: Does it work fine with sbt on the command line? I have compilation errors on my side `Users/etorreborre/projects/scala/sequenceiq-samples/spark-correlation/src/main/scala/com/sequenceiq/spark/Main.scala:3: object apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}`

Comment: This means that sbt or eclipse is not able to find the relevant dependencies.

Comment: I added the spark library into the project. See the EDIT in the question.

Comment: You can download specs2 jars from here: `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/specs2/specs2-core_2.11/3.7` (put `junit` instead of `core` for the JUnit one).